# JavaFX Glitches animating non standard widget

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am trying to prove out an expandable widget with JavaFX that differs from a `TitledPane` in that the border surrounding the label grows with the widget as it expands. I have found a way of doing it.

However I have a weird glitch that shows up after expanding/collapsing once or twice.

This is a link to a short video where the problem appears at the third and fourth expansion:

[Short Youtube Concept / Glitch Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zN3YVKFh2v0&list=UUXt8WvVGvIKGaK9eS0y0d7A)

I've run out of things I could try to get it to behave.

The code is as follows, apologies for the wackiness of it, wanted to get it working before I refactor it.

```
class ExpansionManager {
    enum LayoutState {
        INITIALIZE,
        ANIMATING,
        IDLE,
        REQUEST_ANIMATION
    }

    LayoutState layoutState = LayoutState.INITIALIZE;
    Double fromWidth = 0.0;
    Double fromHeight = 0.0;
    Double stepWidth = 0.0;
    Double stepHeight = 0.0;
    Double toWidth = 0.0;
    Double toHeight = 0.0;
}

public class ExpandableTitledList extends VBox {
    private Label title = new Label();
    private ListProperty<String> listItem = new SimpleListProperty<>();
    private ListView listView = new ListView<>(listItem);
    Timeline timeline;

    WritableValue<Double> writableHeight = new WritableValue<Double>() {
        @Override
        public Double getValue() {
            return expansionManager.stepHeight;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Double value) {
            expansionManager.stepHeight = value;
            requestLayout();
        }
    };

    WritableValue<Double> writableWidth = new WritableValue<Double>() {
        @Override
        public Double getValue() {
            return expansionManager.stepWidth;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Double value) {
            expansionManager.stepWidth = value;
            requestLayout();
        }
    };

    private boolean expanded = false;
    ExpansionManager expansionManager = new ExpansionManager();
//    private Dimension2D contractedDimension;
//    private Dimension2D expandedDimension;


    public ExpandableTitledList() {
        setTitle("boom");
//        title.layout();
//        System.out.println(title.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
        // set down right caret
        listItem.setValue(FXCollections.observableArrayList("one", "two"));

        Insets theInsets = new Insets(-3, -5, -3, -5);
        Border theBorder = new Border(
                new BorderStroke(
                        Color.BLACK,
                        BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                        new CornerRadii(4),
                        new BorderWidths(2),
                        theInsets
                )
        );

//        expandedDimension = new Dimension2D(200,200);

        setBorder(theBorder);
        getChildren().addAll(title);

        title.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
            System.out.println("mouse clicked");
            if (this.expanded) contract();
            else expand();
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        System.out.println(expansionManager.layoutState);
        if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.INITIALIZE) {
            super.layoutChildren();
            expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.IDLE;
        } else if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.ANIMATING) {
            super.layoutChildren();
        } else if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION) {
            setCache(false);
            listView.setCache(false);

            expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.ANIMATING;
            System.out.println("from : " + expansionManager.fromWidth + ", "+ expansionManager.fromHeight);
            System.out.println("to : " + expansionManager.toWidth + ", "+ expansionManager.toHeight);

            timeline = new Timeline();

            timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                            new KeyValue(writableHeight, expansionManager.fromHeight),
                            new KeyValue(writableWidth, expansionManager.fromWidth)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100),
                            new KeyValue(writableHeight, expansionManager.toHeight),
                            new KeyValue(writableWidth, expansionManager.toWidth))
            );
            timeline.play();

            timeline.setOnFinished((done) -> {
                System.out.println("done");
                expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.IDLE;
                timeline = null;
            });

        } else {
            System.out.println("idle");
            super.layoutChildren();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.INITIALIZE) {
            expansionManager.fromHeight = super.computePrefHeight(width);
            return expansionManager.fromHeight;
        } else if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.ANIMATING) {
            return expansionManager.stepHeight;
        } else if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION) {
            expansionManager.fromHeight = getHeight();
            expansionManager.stepHeight = expansionManager.fromHeight;
            expansionManager.toHeight = super.computePrefHeight(width);
            return expansionManager.fromHeight;
        } else {
            return expansionManager.toHeight;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.INITIALIZE) {
            expansionManager.fromWidth = super.computePrefWidth(height);
            return expansionManager.fromWidth;
        } else if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.ANIMATING) {
            return expansionManager.stepWidth;
        } else if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION) {
            expansionManager.fromWidth = getWidth();
            expansionManager.stepWidth = expansionManager.fromWidth;
            expansionManager.toWidth = super.computePrefWidth(height);
            return expansionManager.fromWidth;
        } else {
            System.out.println("BANG BANG BANG");
            return expansionManager.toWidth;
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    protected double computeMinWidth(double height) {
//        return computePrefWidth(height);
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    protected double computeMinHeight(double width) {
//        return computePrefHeight(width);
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    protected double computeMaxWidth(double height) {
//        return computePrefWidth(height);
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    protected double computeMaxHeight(double width) {
//        return computePrefHeight(width);
//    }

    private void expand() {
        System.out.println(expansionManager.layoutState);
//        if(contractedDimension == null)
//            contractedDimension = new Dimension2D(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
//        setPrefSize(expandedDimension.getWidth(), expandedDimension.getHeight());
        expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION;
        this.getChildren().setAll(title, listView);
        expanded = true;

    }

    private void contract() {
//        this.setPrefSize(contractedDimension.getWidth(), contractedDimension.getHeight());
        expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION;
        this.getChildren().setAll(title);
        expanded = false;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title.getText();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added another solution to my answer, in the line with your approach, hope this one will be of your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure out that the `ListView` is the reason why there's a glitch.

Basically, except for the first time, everytime you add the list to the `VBox` you can see the list at its full size for a really brief instant, outside its container, and then when the timeline starts, it's properly resized.

In fact, you can add a delay (one second for instance) to the timeline:

```
timeline.setDelay(Duration.millis(1000));
```

and you'll see the problem for the whole second if you expand the box for the second time:

[image: Glitch]

The list is visible outside the `VBox`, because it isn't resized to fit in it. When the animation starts, it's resized and the problem is gone.

I've tried several approaches to resize the list at that point, without success. Maybe you can solve it...

One ugly solution will be creating a new instance of the list every time you expand the box:

```
private void expand() {
    expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION;
    // this works...    
    listView = new ListView<>(listItem);
    this.getChildren().setAll(title,listView);
    expanded = true;
}
```

Looking for other altenatives, I've bound the box `disableProperty()` to the timeline, so you can't click while the titled list is being expanded or contracted.

So another solution is binding the list `visibleProperty()` to the timeline, but you won't see the nice growing effect.

And there's a third solution, that will also be in line with the animation: set the opacity to 0 right before adding the list to the box:

```
private void expand() {
    expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION;
    // this will avoid seeing the unresized listView
    listView.setOpacity(0);
    this.getChildren().setAll(title,listView);
    expanded = true;
}
```

and add a new `KeyValue` increasing the list `opacityProperty()` from 0 to 1 to the timeline:

```
timeline.getKeyFrames().setAll(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
            new KeyValue(listView.opacityProperty(), 0),
            new KeyValue(writableHeight, expansionManager.fromHeight.get()),
            new KeyValue(writableWidth, expansionManager.fromWidth.get())),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300),
            new KeyValue(listView.opacityProperty(), 1),
            new KeyValue(writableHeight, expansionManager.toHeight.get()),
            new KeyValue(writableWidth, expansionManager.toWidth.get()))
);
```

Now you won't see the glitch, and the list will be showing up nicely while the box is resized. In fact I'll increase the duration of the second keyframe.

[image: List resized]

**EDIT**

I have another alternative to avoid the 'glitch'. Also it could improve the animation, since the list will be visible also when the titled list is contracted.

When you contract the titled list, first of all you remove the list, so `super.computePrefHeight(width)` and `super.computePrefWidth(height)` get the new size of the small box. This has the clear drawback that on the next expand, the list has to be added again, and the glitch happens.

In order to avoid this, we won't remove the list. First, we create two new fields on `ExpansionManager`:

```
Double minWidth = 0.0;
Double minHeight = 0.0;
```

Then we get the minimun size of the box (on the first expansion), and use it for every contraction:

```
@Override
protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
     ...
     if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION) {
        if(expansionManager.minHeight==0d){
            expansionManager.minHeight=getHeight();
        }
        expansionManager.fromHeight = getHeight();
        expansionManager.stepHeight = expansionManager.fromHeight;
        expansionManager.toHeight = expanded?super.computePrefHeight(width):
                                             expansionManager.minHeight;
        return expansionManager.fromHeight;
    }
}

@Override
protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
    ...
    if (expansionManager.layoutState == ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION) {
        if(expansionManager.minWidth==0d){
            expansionManager.minWidth=getWidth();
        }
        expansionManager.fromWidth = getWidth();
        expansionManager.stepWidth = expansionManager.fromWidth;
        expansionManager.toWidth = expanded?super.computePrefWidth(height):
                                            expansionManager.minWidth;
        return expansionManager.fromWidth;
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to hide the list after any contraction, otherwise a small border will be seen, and change the `expand()` and `contract()` methods to call `requestLayout()`, given that the box children list is no longer modified (except on the first call):

```
 @Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
        timeline.setOnFinished((done) -> {
            expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.IDLE;
            listView.setVisible(expanded);
            timeline = null;
        });
}

private void expand() {
    expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION;
    expanded = true;
    listView.setVisible(true);
    if(this.getChildren().size()==1){
        this.getChildren().add(listView);
    }
    requestLayout();
}

private void contract() {
    expansionManager.layoutState = ExpansionManager.LayoutState.REQUEST_ANIMATION;
    expanded = false;
    requestLayout();
}
```